# JComboBox unable to edit or enter text

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jcombobox

I am unable to edit a JComboBox in java. Although I have set the property editable to true but still no use. When I set that property to editable I am unable to even use or select the values in its drop-down list

```
JComboBox comboBoxEmployeeID = new JComboBox();
comboBoxEmployeeID.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"45", "67", "78", "97"}));
comboBoxEmployeeID.setEditable(true);
comboBoxEmployeeID.setEnabled(true);
comboBoxEmployeeID.setBounds(140, 13, 163, 20);
add(comboBoxEmployeeID)
```

one more thing is that when I just view the design in the Eclipse's quickly/test and preview I am getting an editable and perfectly fine working JComboBox but as soon as I Debug the problem arises

[Here is the Quickly/Test and Preview Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKxaF.png)

Comment: Don't use a null layout and setBounds(...). Swing was designed to be used with [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be caused by another part of your code. Can you add the code for the entire frame (or application)? If I test the code in your question (with Java 8 [1.8.0_65] and IntelliJ 15), it is working fine on my machine:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ComboBoxNoChange {
    public static void main(final String[] arguments) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new ComboBoxNoChange().createAndShowGui());
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stack Overflow");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(createComboBox(new String[]{"45", "67", "78", "97"}));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JComboBox<String> createComboBox(String[] employeeIDs) {
        JComboBox<String> employeeIdComboBox = new JComboBox<>();
        employeeIdComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(employeeIDs));
        employeeIdComboBox.setEditable(true);
        employeeIdComboBox.setEnabled(true);
        employeeIdComboBox.setBounds(140, 13, 163, 20);

        return employeeIdComboBox;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can panel switching cause the problem somehow

Comment: You mean switching between panels in a frame or in a `JTabbedPane`? Or switching between multiple frames in your application? I don't know how it could influence the combo box. Once it is visible and enabled, I would expect it to work. If you can add the code for the "Wrapper JFrame" in your screenshot, we might be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: the login panel has a perfectly fine working combobox but I think its related to panel switching somehow here is whats done for that
`ChangingPanel.removeAll();`

`ChangingPanel.add(updateuser);`

`updateuser.setVisible(true);`

`repaint();`

Comment: You could try making the `updateuser` component (and other components) visible or invisible, instead of adding or removing it to the `ChangingPanel`. It is hard to say based on a small part of the code; add more code to your question for more advice.